# Ошибка нехватки памяти при обучении Tacotron2 Pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

решил обучить tts Tacotron2 на датасете RUSLAN(22000 аудио записей).
Использую одну видеокарту A4000 20Gb
При обучении даных с batch_size=8 на 2000+ итерации падает ошибка:

> torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate
> 2.00 MiB (GPU 0; 19.68 GiB total capacity; 17.58 GiB already allocated; 2.00 MiB free; 18.32 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If
> reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb
> to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and
> PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

пытался ставить переменную окружения PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF, но, к сожалению, ничего не меняется
Пробовал очищать кэш а начале каждой итерации, но тоже не помогло

```
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Не могли бы люди сведущие подсказать в чем может быть проблема?
может данные для обучение какие то аномальные попадаются?
Или стоит еще сильнее занизить batch_size?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: Ну да, сходу только ещё снижать `batch_size` пробовать.

Comment: ну вот снизил batch_size до 5, в итоге все равно упало на 15000+ шаге, хотелось бы понять все таки как можно решить проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Здесь](https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2/issues/13) предлагают несколько вариантов решения проблемы. Основное:

- Уменьшить `batch_size`
- Увеличить `reduction_factor` (или `outputs_per_step` - там непонятно написано), но не более чем до `5`, больше будет шум
- Убрать из датасета сэмплы длиной больше чем `20с`, длинные сэмплы - реальная проблема
- Снизить частоту сэмплов, если она выше `16Khz` до `16Khz` или даже до `8Khz`, но качество может пострадать, нужно смотреть